# Checkbox in imageview

Tags: android

I am having a requirement to have checkbox in imageview,how to design the  layout.xml file  for that,on click of the imageview the checkbox sholud be checked. I can handle the job of  checking the checkbox when clicked on imageview. Can any one solve my problem to design simple layout of checkbox should lie in ImageView.

Comment: Are you saying you have checkbox as a image? or a checkbox on some other image?

Comment: checkbox should lie on imageview

Comment: you can use relative layout for that in which check box is overlapping that image

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Comment: i have posted the answer @user2285035

Comment: post your layout. we will help you.

Comment: did your problem solve??

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer
use it in custom adapter class

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtPersonName"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtPersonName" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

***Updated xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/txtPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtPersonName" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not beside the imageview,checkbox should lie on imageview

Comment: its there have you seen its graphical layout??

Comment: you can drag the checkbox where ever you want on the image you are using

Comment: i posted the image can u design simple layout with four image in a row

Comment: am dragging the checkbox but some problem with the layout allignment

Comment: i have updated the answer please check @user2285035
i have replaced match_parent with wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FrameLayout` for that. So your first view inside layout will be overlapped by the second view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/album_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="#ddeeee"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

I have just given a fixed width and height and just background for ImageView. Not `src`. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

You will get the same result using RelativeLayout, but that might vary based on width and height of ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/album_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="#ddeeee"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: cant i do it without framelayout

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample for one image with checkbox in bottom left

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/earth"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New CheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I want the layout like this.On each image a check box should be there.I did it but the check box is not aligned properly.any suggestions

Comment: okk do you have a requirement of a list view or you are ok without it??

Comment: no need of listview..i think by seeing the image above you got my requirement the symbols should be matched with colors...